# Does Thread#join() let other threads through synchronized blocks?

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

The `Object#wait()` method has this funny property that it will allow other threads to enter it's synchronized block while it is blocked in it. Example (assume thread 1 runs first):

Thread 1:

```
synchronized(someLock)
{
    wait();
}
```

Thread 2:

```
synchronized(someLock)
{
    notify();
}
```

The fact that thread 2 is able to wake up thread 1 means that thread 2 entered the synchronized block even though some other thread was in a synchronized block on the same object. That's fine with me but I'm wondering if that happens only for `Object#wait()` or for all methods that would make the thread "wait" (`Thread#sleep, Thread#join`).  In my case I care about `Thread#join` because if the behavior is the same as `Object#wait()` it would break my code:

```
private void waitForClose()
{
    try
    {
        // if one thread is waiting in join the other will wait on the semaphore
        synchronized(joinLock)
        {
            if(outputThread != null && Thread.currentThread() != outputThread)
                outputThread.join();
            outputThread = null;

            if(inputThread != null && Thread.currentThread() != inputThread)
                inputThread.join();
            inputThread = null;
        }
    }
    catch(InterruptedException ex)
    {
        logger.error("Interrupted Exception while waiting for thread to join in " + name, ex);
    }
}
```

So is it possible that multiple threads enter this synchronized block because of the join call putting the thread in a waiting state?

Comment: There is no semaphore in your code here.  You should say that it is waiting on the `joinLock` or on it's monitor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all the `wait` and `notify` mechanism is not really that funny. It is the most rudimentary way of coordinating two or more threads in Java. It is important to understand what is happening here:

Thread 1:

```
synchronized (someLock) {
  System.out.println("Thread 1 going to wait ...");
  someLock.wait();
  System.out.println("Threads 1 got notified.");
}
```

Thread 2:

```
synchronized (someLock) {
  System.out.println("Notifying");
  someLock.notify();
  System.out.println("Exiting block.");
}
```

The `wait()` call will relinquish the lock allowing another thread to take hold of it. At this point, thread 1 will not be able to proceed **even if it gets notified**. This documentation clearly states this:

> The awakened thread will not be able to proceed until the current
>   thread relinquishes the lock on this object.

So it is only after thread 2 exits the `synchronized` block that thread 1 will proceed with the code after the `wait()`.

`Thread.join()` is syntactic sugar, a helper method that underneath the hood makes use of the same `wait` and `notify` / `notifyAll()` methods. In fact the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#join-long-) warns against using `wait` and `notify` on `Thread` objects, not to interfere with this mechanism.

> This implementation uses a loop of this.wait calls conditioned on
>   this.isAlive. As a thread terminates the this.notifyAll method is
>   invoked. It is recommended that applications not use wait, notify, or
>   notifyAll on Thread instances.

`Thread.sleep()` is unrelated to `wait` and `notify`. It does not need an object's lock, and does not need to be in a `synchronized` block.

Your code seems to be synchronizing on an object called `joinLock` while the `outputThread.join()` will be synchronizing and waiting on the `outputThread` object. They are unrelated. If anything you might risk a dead lock if `outputThread` is synchronizing on `joinLock`. Without the code for the `outputThread` I can't say.

Comment: You are talking about the Java _implementation_ when you mention what `Thread.join()` does.  That is not at all in the language specification.

Comment: @Gray Well, being pedantic about the language specification is not really useful for the OP's question. He is clearly asking about what the *Java implementation* is doing and whether it could mess up his code, and using the Thread's monitors and then using `join` is just a recipe for disaster. You should *always* use separate objects to perform your own locking, and leave the Thread's object monitor for its own use.